# venn diagram of power set and empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to describe the empty set by using the venn diagram?

Also what is the venn diagram of a power set of a set with $n$ elements?

Comment: The power set of a set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ elements

Answer (score 1):

The power set of a set with $n$ elements can be illustrated with a Venn diagram that has $n$ overlapping regions. The set with elments $1,2$ and $3$ but not $4$ or $5$ is represented by the region which is formed by the intersection of regions $1,2$, and $3$ with the intersections of the complements (exteriors) of $4$ and $5$, in a graph like [this one](http://statgen.org/wp-content/uploads/Softwares/CNVAnalysisToolkit/docs/_images/venn.png) that I found. The venn diagram of the empty set I'm not sure about. Maybe just a point.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent empty set, just like any other set in Venn diagram, but it is always in region that is formed by intersection of all other sets, and it (empty set) doesn't have any elements.